# MySQL JOIN vs MySQL IN with SubQuery

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I have 2 table foo2 and foo3 with the pictures below. These tables have unique column -> id.

table foo2:

[image]

table foo3:

[image]

I want to select data from two tables with same id. I have 2 query like this

**query1:**

```
SELECT
  foo2.id,
  foo2.`name`
FROM
  foo2
WHERE foo2.id IN (SELECT id FROM foo3);
```

**query2:**

```
SELECT
    foo2.id,
    foo2.`name`
FROM
    foo2
INNER JOIN foo3 ON (foo2.id = foo3.id);
```

These queries return same data. I want to know which one is better? Which one is efficient?

*Thanks for answers.*

Comment: Depends on the data. For large data a join is normally better.

Comment: query1 cuz `join` perform for execution

Comment: Use `EXPLAIN` and look what the query planner tells you: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-explain.html

Comment: Logically, `name` is the `PRIMARY KEY`.  Get rid of `id` and promote `name` to be the PK.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know which performs better, then test the two queries on your data and on your system.

It is important to note that the two queries are *not* the same.  They may return the same value on your data, but the `JOIN` could return duplicate rows, if there are duplicates in `foo3`.

As a personal preference, I would tend to use `JOIN` rather than `IN` if the two are going to return the same rows (say, because I know that `foo3.id` is unique).

Answer (score 0):

You can go with **`Query2`** approach.

As mention by you in second approach **`INNER JOIN`** may good in scenario where table **`foo3`** had millions of rows. So **where** clause may took more time then **`INNER JOIN`**.